# Rails.ajax - Rails is not defined - Rails 7

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I am trying to follow this tutorial to implement sortablejs:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r884jAqAbHY

I'd like to persist the state by sending an ajax update to the server.  The tutorial (Rails 6) does this via `Rails.ajax`

In Rails 7, this causes the console error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Rails is not defined
```

What is the "Rails way" of doing asynchronous requests in Rails 7?

Answer (score 3):

Fetch works - I don't know if it is the "Rails way". . .

```
fetch("URL", {
  method: "PATCH", 
  headers: {
    "X-CSRF-Token": document.querySelector("[name='csrf-token']").content,
  },
  body: data,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/rails/request.js#how-to-use

e.g.

```
import { FetchRequest } from '@rails/request.js'

....

async myMethod () {
  const request = new FetchRequest('post', 'localhost:3000/my_endpoint', { body: JSON.stringify({ name: 'Request.JS' }) })
  const response = await request.perform()
  if (response.ok) {
    const body = await response.text
    // Do whatever do you want with the response body
    // You also are able to call `response.html` or `response.json`, be aware that if you call `response.json` and the response contentType isn't `application/json` there will be raised an error.
  }
}
```